# Laravel: cant get image from local /app

Tags: php, image, laravel, controller, storage

I can upload a image and see the image in **storage/app**/(abc.jpg)

and set the ***'root' => storage_path('app'),*** in filesystems.php

account.blade.php

```
<img src="{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => $user->user_id . '.jpg']) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/userimage/{filename}', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getUserImage',
        'as' => 'account.image'
        ]);
```

Controller

```
public function getUserImage()
    {
        $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
        return new Response($file, 200);
    }
```

> GET
>   http://localhost:8000/userimage/00bea23ff9dd07e5b175c0f8a9283ca8.jpg
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Provide server logs for that request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller method you need to define $filename like this...

```
public function getUserImage($filename)
```